# Finding value in assigned variable

Tags: javascript

```
var ball = 0;
var strike = 0;

function throwBall(){
    ball++;
    var percent = strike / (ball + strike);
    var round = percent.toFixed(2) * 100;
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = round + "%";

    if (round <= 60){
        document.getElementById("winner").src = "";
    }
}
function throwStrike(){
    strike++;
    var percent = strike / (ball + strike);
    var round = percent.toFixed(2) * 100;
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = round + "%";
     if (round > 60){
       document.getElementById("winner").src =            "https://media.giphy.com/media/NxA9Wmq8ISblK/giphy.gif";
}
}
```

throwball is onclick event whenever i would click value of ball will      increment. but in second line var percent according to my calculation its value should be zero hence it should not work but instead of that whenever i click on button the function throwball executes and work properly and give some value instead of giving zero. similar for the second case throwstrike but both are working properly i want to find out how is that work if anybody explain me line by line it would be appreciative.

Comment: make a jsfiddle please..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y637hewf/1/ ?

Comment: we are not here to `explain me line by line`!!

Comment: It seems to work fine.. What is the problem? Or what should it do that it doesn't do now?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: philip just tell me what is the value of var percent ?

Comment: fryane konock i am beginner if i were you i would explain it line by line if somebody asked me  it hardly will take 5 mins to explain it all .

Comment: You should really familiarize yourself with a Javascript REPL (read-eval-print loop). nodejs has one (if you happen to have that installed just type `node` and there you are). Otherwise, you can even use Google Chrome (F12, Console). Type in each line and examine the values of each variable. This will tell you what each line is doing. See here: https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/repl.html

Answer (score 0):

In your `onclick` event as you have mentioned, you call `throwBall()`. You increment `ball` by one prior to evaluation of

```
    var percent = strike / (ball + strike);
```

`percent` is now equal to `0`.

The following line will therefore evaluate to `0`:

```
    var round = percent.toFixed(2) * 100;
```

Therefore, `round <= 60` evaluates to `true`.

So based upon your logic, this surely works the way it is coded. If this is not what you are expecting, then you should reexamine your requirements.

Comment: thx rai i understand it now it was very simple how stupid i am thx anyway